# WinSCP session event handler through COM interface using pywin32

Tags: python-3.x, com, pywin32, winscp

I want to get file transfer progress info while files uploading to webdav server. I try to using WithEvents for set handler for Session object but it stops with error:

```
C:\Miniconda3\python.exe E:/backup_1c/winscp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/backup_1c/winscp.py", line 16, in <module>
    wcpSession.open(winscp_session_option)
  File "<COMObject WinSCP.Session>", line 2, in open
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Error.', (0, 'mscorlib', 'Member group not found. (Exception HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))', None, 0, -2147352573), None)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Script code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
import win32com.client as win32

class WinScp_ISessionEvents:
    def OnFileTransferProgress(self, e):
        print(e.FileProgress)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    wcpSession = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('WinSCP.Session')
    winscp_session_option = win32.dynamic.Dispatch('WinSCP.SessionOptions')
    winscp_session_option.Protocol = 3
    winscp_session_option.HostName = "webdav.yandex.ru/"
    winscp_session_option.UserName = "user"
    winscp_session_option.Password = "password"
    win32.WithEvents(wcpSession, WinScp_ISessionEvents)
    wcpSession.open(winscp_session_option)
    wcpSession.PutFiles('E:\Exchange\File.xls', '/File.xls')
```

According to error message I have wrong function name in WinScp_ISessionEvents class, I have tried different names such as FileTransferProgress, Session_FileTransferProgress, wcpSession_FileTransferProgress, wcpSession_OnFileTransferProgress, and many many others.

Answer (score 0):

The callstack shows a problem at the `wcpSession.open`, not the `win32.WithEvents`.

Isn't the problem that the method is `.Open`, not `.open`?

Comment: I have just use both Open and open methods but nothing changes.
If I comment string win32.WithEvents(wcpSession, WinScp_ISessionEvents) then script work correct, and finish with exit code 0.